# Redirection and form's processing totally ignored by Symfony

Tags: forms, symfony, redirect

Symfony doesn't redirect even when I put the redirection right after the start of the it's processing *(Minimalist example)* :

```
if($formPhoto->isSubmitted() && $formPhoto->isValid()){
   $this->redirectToRoute('app_acc');
}
```

It seems like Symfony never enter in the processing. However, the data are send properly to the database, and when I put a `dump('Hello');` instead of the `$this->redirectToRoute('app_acc');` I see it on the refreshed page, so Symfony enter in it.

In my routes.yaml I have this : *(I know it works well because used elsewhere)*

```
app_acc:
path: /{_locale}
controller: App\Controller\AccueilController::index
defaults:
    _locale: fr
requirements:
    _locale: en|fr
```

I don't understand why does Symfony ignore my redirections & some of my processings ?
Does someone has an idea ? I'm starting to go crazy. 
Thank you

Comment: return $this->redirectToRoute('app_acc');

Comment: I feel so bad. thank you Cerad.

Comment: Glad, it was solved. I voted close as this is simply caused by a typo, so probably no need to keep the question up.

Comment: @dbrumann - Technically not a typo.  Just a missing return statement.  The sort of question does pop up ever so often.  The name of the method call does suggest an immediate redirect when in fact it merely return a RedirectRepsonse.

Comment: True, "typo" is not the right word. Since it pops up every so often I still think there is no value in leaving each of them open. Someone else encountering the issue, will likely not find this question unless it happens in very similar circumstances.